Generate Multi-Page PDF Reports in Python with Tables, Headers, Footers, and Adjustable Cell Data (using reportlab)
I want to Generate Multi-Page PDF Reports in Python with Tables, Headers, Footers, and Adjustable Cell Data (using reportlab)
However, the fontsize is not changing for the content of the table for a weird reason...
I have tried to change here:
('FONTSIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 24),  # Font size for content
but nothing happens
import time
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import landscape, letter
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph, PageTemplate, Frame
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

# Function to add header and footer
def add_header_footer(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    # Header
    header_text = "Report Header"
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica-Bold', 14)
    text_width = canvas.stringWidth(header_text, 'Helvetica-Bold', 14)
    canvas.drawCentredString(doc.pagesize[0] / 2, doc.pagesize[1] - 80, header_text)  # Adjusted position
    
    # Footer
    footer_text = f"Page {doc.page}"
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 10)
    text_width = canvas.stringWidth(footer_text, 'Helvetica', 10)
    canvas.drawString((doc.pagesize[0] - text_width) / 2, 40, footer_text)
    canvas.restoreState()

# Function to generate PDF with ordered data in a table format
def generate_pdf(data, pdf_filename):
    # Create the document
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_filename, pagesize=landscape(letter), topMargin=1.5*inch)  # Adjust topMargin here
    
    # Define the table data
    table_data = [['Parameter Name', 'Expected Value', 'Your INI Value']]
    
    # Get the sample style sheet
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    styleN = styles['Normal']
    
    # Add "Results for the Ini file:" text as a paragraph before the table
    results_text = "Results for the Ini file:"
    results_paragraph = Paragraph(results_text, styles['Heading2'])
    
    # Calculate the height of the results paragraph
    results_paragraph_height = results_paragraph.wrap(doc.width, doc.topMargin)[1]
    
    # Populate the table with data
    for i in range(len(data['Parameter_Name'])):
        # Ensure each cell in the row is a Paragraph object
        row = [
            Paragraph(data['Parameter_Name'][i], styleN),
            Paragraph(data['Expected_Value'][i], styleN),
            Paragraph(data['Your_INI_Value'][i], styleN)
        ]
        
        table_data.append(row)
    
    # Create the table
    table = Table(table_data, colWidths=[2.5 * inch, 3.0 * inch, 3.0 * inch], repeatRows=1)  # use repeatRows=1 if you want the header of the table to be repetad in teh table in the next pages
    
    # Add style to the table
    style = TableStyle([
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.grey),
        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.whitesmoke),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
        ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 14), # For header in table
        ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 8),
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 1), (-1, -1), colors.beige),
        ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),
        ('FONTNAME', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'Helvetica'),
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 24),  # Font size for content
        ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP'),  # Ensure text starts from the top of the cell
    ])
    table.setStyle(style)

    # Apply conditional styling for rows where values differ
    for i in range(1, len(table_data)):  # Start from 1 to skip header row
        expected_value = data['Expected_Value'][i-1]
        your_ini_value = data['Your_INI_Value'][i-1]
        if expected_value != your_ini_value:
            # Apply red background and white text for differing rows
            table.setStyle(TableStyle([
                ('BACKGROUND', (0, i), (-1, i), colors.red),
                ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, i), (-1, i), colors.white)
            ]))

    # Define the frame for the page template
    frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin + 5 + results_paragraph_height, doc.width, doc.height - 5 - results_paragraph_height, id='normal')
    # frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin + 100 + results_paragraph_height, doc.width, doc.height - 100 - results_paragraph_height, id='normal')
    
    # Add the PageTemplate with header and footer
    template = PageTemplate(id='test', frames=frame, onPage=add_header_footer)
    doc.addPageTemplates([template])
    
    # # Calculate row heights for each row in the table
    # row_heights = []
    # for row in table_data:
    #     # Ensure all elements in row are Paragraph objects
    #     if all(isinstance(cell, Paragraph) for cell in row):
    #         row_heights.append(max([p.wrap(doc.width, doc.height)[1] for p in row]))
    
    # # Remove the header row height
    # if row_heights:
    #     header_row_height = row_heights.pop(0)
    # else:
    #     header_row_height = 0
    
    # Build the PDF
    elements = [results_paragraph, table]
    doc.build(elements, onFirstPage=add_header_footer, onLaterPages=add_header_footer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Example data (20 parameters with fictitious names and values)
    data = {
        'Parameter_Name': [
            'Parameter 1', 'Parameter 2', 'Parameter 3', 'Parameter 4', 'Parameter 5',
            'Parameter 6', 'Parameter 7', 'Parameter 8', 'Parameter 9', 'Parameter 10',
            'Parameter 11', 'Parameter 12', 'Parameter 13', 'Parameter 14', 'Parameter 15',
            'Parameter 16', 'Parameter 17', 'Parameter 18', 'Parameter 19', 'Parameter 20'
        ],
        'Expected_Value': [
            'Value 1', 'Expected Value 2', 'Expected Value 3', 'Expected Value 4', 'Expected Value 5',
            'Expected Value 6', 'Value 7', 'Expected Value 8', 'Expected Value 9', 'Expected Value 10',
            'Expected Value 11', 'Expected Value 12', 'Expected Value 13', 'Expected Value 14', 'Expected Value 15',
            'Expected Value 16', 'Value 17', 'Expected Value 18', 'Expected Value 19', 'Expected Value 20'
        ],
        'Your_INI_Value': [
            'Value 1', 'Your INI Value 2', 'Your INI Value 3', 'Your INI Value 4', 'Your INI Value 5',
            'Your INI Value 6', 'Value 7', 'Your INI Value 8', 'Example of large data for a cell, and autoadjust for Your INI Value 9', 'Your INI Value 10',
            'Your INI Value 11', 'Your INI Value 12', 'Your INI Value 13', 'Your INI Value 14', 'Your INI Value 15',
            'Your INI Value 16', 'Value 17', 'Your INI Value 18', 'Your INI Value 19', 'Your INI Value 20'
        ]
    }
    # PDF filename with timestamp
    # pdf_filename = f"ordered_data_{time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.pdf"
    pdf_filename = f"ordered_data.pdf"
    
    # Generate the PDF with ordered data
    generate_pdf(data, pdf_filename)
    print(pdf_filename)


Any solution??


I notice that since each cell in the row is a Paragraph object, it needs to have set the Fontsize for that object, so I basically modified this variable 'styleN', so now it works:
# Define a custom style for table cells
styleN = ParagraphStyle(
    name='CellStyle',
    parent=styles['Normal'],
    fontName='Times-Roman',
    fontSize=12,  # Set the desired font size here for the cells
    leading=12
)

